# How to write pow math?

Tags: math-mode

I want to write math:

```
{i^{w}}^{anterior}
```

but this is the result:

[image]

I want this :

[image]

Comment: ignoring the font or size, you might consider `i^{w^{anterior}}`  as in `2^{2^{3}} = 256`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Embrace the `{w^{\mathrm{anterior}}}` rather than the `{i^{w}}`.  Also, `\mathrm` for math-sized **text** (by "text", I mean phonetic language, not a collection of math symbols).

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
$i^{w^{\mathrm{anterior}}}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I would add the admonition: if you don't use `\mathrm` but simply write `anterior` without any special control sequence, it is typeset as a product of variables term: a times n times t times e ... not what you want.

Comment: @Kaz That is what I implied with the word "text", but have clarified, since it caused you some confusion.

Comment: I am obviously not confused in any way myself.

Comment: @Kaz I am sorry to have implied that.  You are trying to help the reader, I understand.

Comment: What is the difference between \mathrm and \text?

Comment: @ThomasAhle In this case, nothing, except that `\text` requires the `amsmath` package.  If the operated-upon text had, for example, punctuation, `\mathrm` would apply the `\mathpunct`, whereas `\text` would not.

Answer (score 10):

If I understood you correctly, you want the superscripts have `normalsize` plus an `sf` shape, you can use `\mbox`.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\begin{document}

\newcommand{\mb}[1]{\mbox{\sffamily#1\,}}
$\mb{i}^{\mb{w}^{\mb{anterior}}}$

\end{document}
```

> [image]

Answer (score 2):

Another good approach is `\operatorname{anterior}` from `amsmath`, especially if you want two of these variables to appear consecutively.

Personally, I would prefer to define `\newcommand\anterior{\operatorname{anterior}}`, analogously to `\sin` or `\log`.

Answer (score 1):

In your version `{i^{w}}^{anterior}`, the `i` is effectively raised to two separate exponents, causing them to appear side-by-side, which is not what you intend: [image]

If you nest the braces as `{i^{w^{anterior}}}` then the stack of exponents is preserved, resulting in what appears to be your desired form: [image]

(This is assuming it's stacked exponents that you're concerned with, not plain text formatting for superscripts as your example image might suggest. In that case, use [AboAmmar's version](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/475693/181926).)